# OS X - way of seeing what app is using how much bandwidth?

Tags: macos, mac, display, bandwidth

I use iStatMenu to show me my total bandwidth use at any moment, but what I really want it a way of seeing what app is using how much. Sometimes I see more bandwidth being used that I expect, but I have no way of seeing which is the greedy app!

Ideally I'd prefer a free app of course, and not something as intrusive as LittleSnitch, I don't want to control what apps can use the web, just monitor them.

Answer (score 1):

if you've got 10.7, you can use the shockingly verbose command ->

`nettop [ route | tcp | udp ]`

It presents a display of EVERY SINGLE network connection, by process, including...

`state      packets in        bytes in     packets out       bytes out`

Don't forget to use the arrow keys (or `return`) to "go down" the HUGE list.

Comment: `-bash: tcp: command not found` and `-bash: udp: command not found` from `~$` on my Lion (10.7.1).

Comment: `nettop` is the command, `[ udp | tcp | route ]` indicate the *optional* arguments to that command (amongst others).  `man *command*` shows the options and usage for any command..